# How to recalculate a user defined variable for every loop/thread in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter script that registers each user with a random email address and random password.
This is the way I've managed this.

[image]

My question is how can I recalculate these values for each thread/loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save variable with the value using [__RandomString](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) 3rd parameter. Example:

```
 ${__RandomString(6,a12zeczclk, MYVAR)}
```

And then use `${MYVAR}` with the value you used.

Repeated call for the function will override variable value.

If the question is about loading username value again per loop, you should move to use User Parameters as pre processor instead of [user defined variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables). So it will be recalculated every time and not just on load.

> For defining variables during a test run, see User Parameters. UDVs are processed in the order they appear in the Plan, from top to bottom.

Comment: The second part is what I was aiming for and it works for me. Tnx for the quick answer.